# macOS Swift: Updating a NSTextfield based off input from NSComboBox

Tags: swift, macos

I am working on my Swift and teaching myself as I go.

So far, I've built a decent notation app for my job, to help generate notes for cases that we work. I'm trying to implement a feature where a user can type the name of a company in a NSComboBox and then, if there is a relevant key match in the NSDictionary, a secondary text field updates with the relevant value from the dictionary.

This is designed this way as there may be instances where a company is not saved and so the text is entered into these fields manually.

I have the code functional, so long as the user inputs something from the dictionary. If the user types something into the "companyName" field, the whole thing crashes because it gets a nil response.  I've tried all different manners of guard tags or if statements and I'm definitely just doing something wrong so I'm hoping for guidance in how to make it not crash when something is entered manually.

(I'm controlling most of these elements via Xcode UI builder, which is why items for ComboBox aren't outlined in Code, FYI)

```
@IBOutlet weak var companyID: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var companyName: NSComboBox!
    
    var theCompanies: NSDictionary? = ["Company 1" : "1", "Company 2" : "2"]
    var theID = ""
    @IBAction func nameUpdated(_ sender: Any) {
        let theID = theCompanies?.value(forKey: companyName.stringValue) as! String
        self.companyID.stringValue = theID
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I've played with this a bit more and I finally got it, in case anyone else in the future is trying to track this down.

Final code turned out to be:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var companyID: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var companyName: NSComboBox!
    
    var theCompanies: NSDictionary? = ["Company 1" : "1", "Company 2" : "2"]
    var theID = ""

    
    
    @IBAction func nameUpdated(_ sender: Any) {
        let theID = theCompanies?.value(forKey: companyName.stringValue) as? String
        self.companyID.stringValue = theID ?? ""
    }
```

Taking Kiril's advise, I removed the force unwrap, but couldn't get the guard statement to work. On a whim, I set a default value of "" for companyID.stringValue and that did the trick. The optional unwrap coupled with the default value for the set command hooked it up properly.

Comment: "can't have a guard statement declare a variable" <--- makes no sense to me. Unwrapping optional and assigning it to a variable (e.g. guard let x = someStuffCanBeNil else {... is a text book use of guard. You should really take time and learn the language properly.